# A property of the topological disjoint sum

Tags: general-topology

Following a reference from " Elementos de Topología general" by Angel Tamariz and Fidel Casarrubias

> For a collection $\mathcal{G}=\{(X_j ,\mathcal{T}_j):j\in J\}$ of topological spaces let be $X=\bigcup_{j\in J}X_j$ and we consider for each $j\in J$ the inclusion function $\iota_j:X_j\rightarrow X$ defined as $\iota_j(x)=x$: so for $\mathcal{F}=\{\iota_j:j\in J\}$ we can consider the final topology $\mathcal{T}_\mathcal{F}=\{E\subseteq X:\iota^{-1}_j(E)\in\mathcal{T}_j, \forall j\in J\}$. Well we call the topological space $(X,\mathcal{T}_\mathcal{F})$ topological sum of the collection $\mathcal{G}$; moreover for each collection $\mathcal{G}=\{(X_j ,\mathcal{T}_j):j\in J\}$ of topological spaces we can consider the collection $\{X_j\times \{j\}:j\in J\}$ and using produtc topology $\mathcal{T}_{\pi_j}$ for each $j\in J$ (naturally the only topology with which it is possible equipped $\{j\}$ is the discrete topology that in this case is equal to the indiscrete topology) we can consider the topological sum of the collection $\mathcal{G'}=\{(X_j\times\{j\} ,\mathcal{T}_{\pi_j}):j\in J\}$, that we call topological disjoint sum of $\mathcal{G}$. In particular we can observe that the open sets of this topology are union of the open setes of the addend spaces, as you can see in the in the picture below.

[image]

Well I don't understeand why the open sets of the disjoint topological sum are union of the open sets of the addend spaces. Could someone explain to me this formally, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confusing things. First $\coprod_{j \in J} X_j$ (the coproduct or topological sum) should be the "disjointified" union $$\bigcup_{j \in J} X_j \times \{j\}$$ and the injections are $\sigma_j(x)=(x,j)$ for all $j \in J$.

Then $\coprod_{j \in J} X_j$ indeed has the final topology $\mathcal{T}_f$ wrt the injections $\sigma_j:(X,\mathcal{T}_j) \to X$ as you describe. Open sets $O$ in $\coprod_{j \in J} X_j$ can be naturally written as $$ O = \bigcup_{j \in J} O \cap \sigma_j[X] = \bigcup_{j \in J} \sigma_j[\sigma_j^{-1}[O]]$$ which we can see as a union of (homeomorphic copies of) open subsets from the $X_j$.

We could also form the union $X = \bigcup_{j \in J} X_j$ and have injections $\iota_j(x)=x$ and get a final topology $\mathcal{T}'_f$ on $X$ wrt those injections. But then we need assumptions on the $X_j$ and their mutual relations to have any nice meaningful topology on $X$. E.g. suppose that $X_1=[0,1]$ in its usual topology and $X_2 = [0,1]$ in the discrete topology. Then, when executing this construction, $X \simeq X_1$. There is no trace of $X_2$ anymore. We cannot distinguish between the $\frac{1}{2}$ that comes from $X_1$ and the one from $X_2$ etc. Open sets in $X$ are not unions of open sets from $X_1$ and $X_2$ any more. This construction is never done in practice; it doesn't seem to be useful. The standard sums (first part) are very common however, mostly as a tool in other results.

One common exception where the product view can be valid: if all $X_j$ are the same topological space, say $\forall j: (X_j, \mathcal{T}_j)=(Y, \mathcal{T}_Y)$. In that case $\coprod_{j \in J} X_j \simeq Y \times J$ where $J$ has the discrete (!) topology and $Y \times J$ has the product topology. The homeomorphism is just the identity, which is well-defined on the set level. Check that it's continuous and open between these topologies..

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understeand the injections $\sigma_j:(X ,\mathcal{T}_j)\rightarrow X$, since indeed for me it should be $\sigma_j:(X_j ,\mathcal{T}_j)\rightarrow X$ where naturally $X=\bigcup_{j\in J}X_j\times\{j\}$. Then I studied that by using final topology the open sets $O$ in X must be that sets such that $\sigma^{-1}_j(O)\in\mathcal{T}_j$, so could you explain to me why instead $O = \bigcup_{j \in J} O \cap \sigma_j[X] = \bigcup_{j \in J} \sigma_j[\sigma_j^{-1}[O]]$?

Comment: Finally the definition I gave of "Sum Topology$ is that I read in my text of Topology ( Elementos de Topología general by Angel Tamariz and Fidel Casarrubias): I think is the same that is described [here](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/topological-sums-of-topological-spaces). Sorry, forgive my confusion: so could you help me, please?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro I use the same $\sigma_j$ as you do, don't I? And the same $X$. The online source has a different setup: there they assume the spaces *are* pairwise disjoint and the normal union works and the injections are subset inclusions.  But the general sum construction needs the $\times \{j\}$ or similar disjointification. The $\sigma_j$ then becomes open embeddings and we use the final topology. My $O$ decomposition is trivial and is the same as the online source where we use unions of open sets of the $X_j$.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Every $O \subseteq X$ can be partitioned into those $(x,j) \in O$ with for different $j$, i.e. in the sets $O \cap \sigma_j[X]$. The set $O \cap \sigma_j[X]$ has as its pre-image under $\sigma_j$ in essence the "projection" $\pi_j[O]$, as it were, and this set must be open in $X_j$ by definition of open subsets of $X$ so we can see $O \cap (X_j \times \{j\})$ as $\sigma_j[\sigma_j^{-1}[O]]$, which we can sort of see as an open subset of $X_j$ if we identify $X_j$ and its image $\sigma_j[X_j]$ as is commonly done.

Comment: Okay, now it's clear. Thanks!